# notifyDataSetChanged only refreshes GridView once, despite being called multiple times

Tags: android

I will attempt to summarize my code as follows:

- I have a TileAdapter which extends from BaseAdapter to populate a GridView
- My TileAdapter contains an array of Tiles that is used to maintain state
- My TileUpdate class performs the following operations:

  1. Changes Tile A's colour to green
  2. Calls TileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  3. Changes Tile B's colour to yellow
  4. Calls TileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  5. Changes Tile B's colour to red
  6. Calls TileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

I would have expected to see my GridView refresh 3 times, once for each call to notifyDataSetChanged().

However, I only see it refresh after step 6, when and never see Tile B turn yellow.

What is happening here? I presume there is some part of the API I'm not aware of.

Thanks

**Update**

I still have not been successful in implementing this, even after studying the Handler approaches described below.
So in my UI thread I've created a new GridOperationQueue class which extends from Thread:

```
public class GridOperationQueue extends Thread {
private Handler handler;

@Override
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();

    handler = new Handler();

    Looper.loop();  

}

public void addTaskToQueue(final GridUpdateTask task)
{
    Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "Current thread is ID " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    handler.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), " Handler task's current thread is ID " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            task.run();
        }

    });
}

public void clearQueue(){
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

}

So my UI thread invokes addTaskToQueue providing a new Task object. The idea is that the task's processing will be performed on a separate thread and after it completes invokes a notifyDataSetChanged() on the UI thread.
However, I've added some logging and it seems that when my tasks run they are still running on the main thread....how would this be? See the following logging:

```
GridOperationQueue(4393): Current thread is ID 1
GridOperationQueue(4393): Current thread is ID 1
GridOperationQueue(4393): Current thread is ID 1
GridOperationQueue$1(4393):  Handler task's current thread is ID 9
TileOperationService$1(4393): Current thread is ID 9
MyActivity(4393): Current thread is ID 9
GridOperationQueue$1(4393):  Handler task's current thread is ID 9
TileOperationService$2(4393): Current thread is ID 9
MyActivity(4393): Current thread is ID 9
GridOperationQueue$1(4393):  Handler task's current thread is ID 9
TileOperationService$3(4393): Current thread is ID 9
MyActivity(4393): Current thread is ID 9
```

How come the tasks are still running on the main thread?

Comment: do you perform the following operations right after each other, or are they asynchronous?

Comment: There are a few other steps in between to perform some calculations, that probably take milliseconds. I have no threading in my code, so I presume all are synchronous

Comment: How do you invoke the code above? Do you call it from an event of a button click or other GUI control perhaps?

Comment: You're probably executing your code in the UI thread without giving it a chance to actually change the colors... so, even though you call notiftDataSetChanged() three times, android only gets around to processing the latest set of changes.

Comment: I am invoking this code from within an implementation of OnClickListener. So based, on what you are saying it will only refresh once in this thread?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're making all of those changes in your onClick method. The onClick method runs in the UI thread... so, while the code in onClick is running, the UI thread cannot change and tile colors since it's busy. in fact, notifyDataSetChanged simply sets a flag that tells Android to update the changes to the view **whenever it can**; notifyDataSetChanged does not force an update, but simple tells android one is needed. Thus, you are simply telling android it needs to update the view three times... but, by the time android can actually make the update, which is after your onClick method is done, it can only see the most recent change to the tile color.

How do you get around this? Well, it depends on what you really want to do. for instance, if you want tile color A to change to tile color B when you click the view, and then change to tile color C 500 ms later, do something like this

```
Handler handler; // instance var
public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  handler = new Handler();
}

// in your onClick method, wherever it may be (pseudocode)
public void onClick(View v) {
  1) set tile color to color B
  2) call notifyDataSetChanged
  3) schedule a color change in 500 ms:
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         1) set tile color to color C
         2) call notifyDataSetChanged
       }
     }), 500);
```

Comment: With your help, i got rid of notifyDataSetChanged. Now I just change content and everything works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html). The trouble is that when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` you only trigger a flag to the GUI. When the adapter gets a repaint it checks if the flag is set and takes action. It *does not* take any action directly when you call notify.

If you want to update the GUI directly you should learn about the class Handler (see the previous link) so you can post updates to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but it seems that you are updating twice the color of Tile B (identical steps 3 and 5 on your question). If that's the case, you will only see the last color (red) and yellow will never be displayed, of course.

Or, you meant "Tile C" on step 5. If this is the case, then the following comments might help:

Even if the UI is changing 3 times, you are probably overriding each color on each call.

1) So your three tiles are 'default' color

2) You update Tile A to green

3) notifyDataSetChanged() is called

(your grid view is updated correctly)

4) You update Tile B to yellow

5) notifyDataSetChanged() is called

(your grid view updates Title B to yellow, but overrides Title A to 'default' color.

6) You update Tile C to red

7) notifyDataSetChanged() is called

(your grid view updates Title C to red, but overrides Title A and B to 'default' color.

That could be the issue.

Also, remember as other guys have mentioned, notifyDataSetChanged() does nothing directly. It only signals the UI to be refreshed when the ideal conditions are met.

Comment: No, Tile B is correct, I want it to temporarily refresh before turning red. The issue here appears to be that I am calling these notifies within the same thread. I am going to have to figure out a way to perform these tasks in a separate thread